# How to enable my accidentally disabled "back" and "forward" buttons in VSCode Command centre?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image of empty command centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taf8m.jpg)

I right click toggled off various buttons from my command center - back, forward, search bar. How do I re-enable them?

right-clicking again only shows a toggle for the entire command center but the toggles for the above mentioned buttons have disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Right Click` in that area and select `Command center`

Then `Right Click` on each element you don't want and select `Hide`

**Edit**

Found an [issue talking about the command center disappearing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162598#issuecomment-1272356305)

The [solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162598#issuecomment-1272869327) is command: **View: Reset All Menus**

Comment: How to re-enable those hidden elements? the toggle to hide is shown initially, but after hiding, those toggles are missing

Comment: @Yoko Right click on any other element of the command center and you can toggle each element of the command center

Comment: the "go back" and "go forward" toggles are not showing up when I right-click anywhere, even on other elements in the command centre. https://imgur.com/a/wdjjK5M

Comment: I just Hide all elements in (VSC insiders) and now the command center is 0x0 pixels and you can't get the toggle menu, you have to file an issue at the VSC repo, most likely it adds a callback to the elements of the `ul` tag, but now no elements are there anymore

Comment: @Yoko found the solution, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Visual Studio Code to your liking through its various settings. Nearly every part of VS Code's editor, user interface, and functional behavior has options you can modify.

VS Code provides several different scopes for settings. When you open a workspace, you will see at least the following two scopes:

User Settings - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
Workspace Settings - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.

To modify user settings, you'll use the Settings editor to review and change VS Code settings.

To open the Settings editor, use the following VS Code menu command:

On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings
You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) with Preferences: Open Settings or use the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+,).

When you open the Settings editor, you can search and discover the settings you are looking for. When you search using the Search bar, it will not only show and highlight the settings matching your criteria, but also filter out those which are not matching. This makes finding settings quick and easy.